# How can I view my PDF as a brochure?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, mockup

I made a brochure (4 panels each side) in InDesign and I'd like to see what it would look like folded without printing it out yet. Kinda like an e-magazine or issuu, where you can flip the pages. Does anyone know how I would achieve this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want or how you would benefit from it. You say you want to see how it would look folded, without printing... then you say you want issuu like thing, where you can flip the pages. As far as I'm aware, issuu doesn't fold anything. It just adds navigation. If you want to preview it as folded brochure, maybe search for [brochure mockups](https://www.behance.net/gallery/23962377/Mockup-Fold-Brochure). If you want to navigate the pages/spreads easily or something, maybe check out [Indesign hotkeys](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html)?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is make a new indesign document with the page size set to the height and width of the panels and make 8 pages so you can drag and drop each panel onto the appropriate page and export it as a pdf.  Then you'll be able to flip through each page one by one.

That's about the best you can do in terms of seeing each panel by itself.  There's lifelike brouchure mockups for Photoshop that you can download that will allow you to see what it would look like printed and folded sitting on a table, but they're not interactive so you can't flip the pages.  Only other thing I can suggest is if you happen to be good at 3D design and animation you could save each panel as a JPEG or PNG and model a brochure that you can place them on and animate it unfolding.  Other than that there's nothing I know of that allows you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your need to add some navigation in so that you can move between the pages. Switch to the Interactive for PDF workspace. follow these instructions- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/interactivity-5.html (choosing the forward and back buttons from the sample menu should automatically add the effects to the buttons.

Select the pages- in the page transition menu choose the page turn option. export to SWF, (this will be fine for viewing if you need to send this someone else you may need to covert to PDF) Uncheck the interactive curl option.

This creates a page turn effect, if you want it to look like a brochure when it is flat you will first need to mock up the indesign pages in a PSD brochure template.